# MassTransit vs official azure service bus client sdk

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm setting up a communication between service fabric .net core services using Azure Service Bus and I'm struggling with pros and cons list regarding MassTransit .net core library and an official Azure Service Bus client SDK.

I would like to hear some advice from someone with experience with both libraries. Would be nice to hear about more technical differences: concurrency, deduplication, outbox pattern, error handling, serialization, easy to use

Comment: It's all written in the docs http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/additions-to-transport.html

Comment: MassTransit is an abstraction over (several) concrete implementations (where ServiceBus is one, RabbitMQ is another).  Like most abstractions, you will get "most" functionality of any of the concretes. You may lose some detailed functionalty from any one of them.      http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/introduction/packages.html#transports

Comment: Here is one thing I encountered with RabbitMQ that I didnt' see in ServiceBus.  I don't know if MassTransit has any functionality for it...since the 2 concrete libraries disagree a bit.          https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html